# Список страниц по номерам

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

Я новичок в этом деле.
Как можно делать список страниц в PHP и XHTML? Например:

> Page: 1
>  bla bla bla
>  Pages: Last << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 >> Next

Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм прост: надо задать число вывода записей на страницу, например, это будет 10, то есть 1 страница вмещает в себе 10 записей, скрипту передается параметр, содержащий номер страницы, если параметр равен 1, то выводим записи с 1 по 10, если 2, с 11 по 20, если 3, с 21 по 30. Количество страниц тоже очень легко посчитать, если известно количество записей,  например, 130, а записей на страницу выводится по 10, то 130/10 = 13. Соответственно у нас будет 13 страниц и, обращаясь к скрипту с значением параметра от 1 до 13, мы будем получать содержимое интересующей нас страницы. Вот в этом суть метода разбиения инфо по страницам.

Answer (score 1):

- [Постраничный вывод (PHP и MySQL)](http://tigir.com/paging.htm).
- [Постраничная навигация на PHP](http://php.su/articles/?cat=examples&page=062) (более простой вариант "раз").
- [Постраничный вывод из MySQL](http://experience.barkarola.com/php/2011/03/14/postranichnyy-vyvod-iz-mysql.html) (более простой вариант "два").

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
/**
 * Pager
 *
 */
class PagingViewHelper {

    public function paging($url, $total, $current)
    {
        if ($total <= 1)
            return '';
        if ($total <= 5)
        {
            $contentBlock = array();
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $total; $i++)
            {
                $link = str_replace(':page:', $i, $url);
                if ($i == $current)
                {
                    $contentBlock[] = '<b>'.$i.'</b>';
                } else {
                    $contentBlock[] = '<a href="'.$link.'">'.$i.'</a>';
                }
            }
            $content = join('&nbsp;&nbsp;', $contentBlock);
            $content = preg_replace('#(</p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\|)#is','</p>',$content);
            $content = preg_replace('#(\|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<p)#is','<p',$content);
            return $content;
        }

        if ($current == 1)
        {
            $contentBlock = array();
            for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++)
            {
                $link = str_replace(':page:', $i, $url);
                if ($i == $current)
                {
                    $contentBlock[] = '<b>'.$i.'</b>';
                } else {
                    $contentBlock[] = '<a href="'.$link.'">'.$i.'</a>';
                }
            }
            $link = str_replace(':page:', $current + 1, $url);
            $contentBlock[] = '<a href="'.$link.'">&raquo;</a>';
            $content = join('&nbsp;&nbsp;', $contentBlock);
            $content = preg_replace('#(</p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\|)#is','</p>',$content);
            $content = preg_replace('#(\|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<p)#is','<p',$content);
            return $content;
        }

        if ($total - $current == 0)
        {
            $contentBlock = array();
            $link = str_replace(':page:', $current - 1, $url);
            $contentBlock[] = '<a href="'.$link.'">&laquo;</a>';
            for ($i = $total - 4; $i <= $total; $i++)
            {
                $link = str_replace(':page:', $i, $url);
                if ($i == $current)
                {
                    $contentBlock[] = '<b>'.$i.'</b>';
                } else {
                    $contentBlock[] = '<a href="'.$link.'">'.$i.'</a>';
                }
            }
            $content = join('&nbsp;&nbsp;', $contentBlock);
            $content = preg_replace('#(</p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\|)#is','</p>',$content);
            $content = preg_replace('#(\|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<p)#is','<p',$content);
            return $content;
        }

        $contentBlock = array();
        $link = str_replace(':page:', $current - 1, $url);
        $contentBlock[] = '<a href="'.$link.'">&laquo;</a>';
        for ($i = $current - 2; $i <= $current + 2; $i++)
        {
            if ($i <= $total && $i > 0)
            {
                $link = str_replace(':page:', $i, $url);
                if ($i == $current)
                {
                    $contentBlock[] = '<b>'.$i.'</b>';
                } else {
                    $contentBlock[] = '<a href="'.$link.'">'.$i.'</a>';
                }
            }
        }
        $link = str_replace(':page:', $current + 1, $url);
        $contentBlock[] = '<a href="'.$link.'">&raquo;</a>';
        $content = join('&nbsp;&nbsp;', $contentBlock);
        $content = preg_replace('#(</p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\|)#is','</p>',$content);
        $content = preg_replace('#(\|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<p)#is','<p',$content);
        return $content;
    }
}
```